# Windows/SQL Azure Maintenance Windows?

Tags: sql-server, windows, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-diagnostics

I have a couple of SQL Azure databases deployed. They all seem to work just fine at most times of the day. However, I have recently noticed that there is a consistent set of errors around the 5AM to 7AM PST time (GMT -8). Does anyone know if there are maintenance windows or anything else, server side at Azure, that would consistently cause errors during this hour? I have already checked my code to verify that there isn't anything on the client side that would cause this type of consistency in errors.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a maintenance windows of Azure. It could well be (and likely is) a maintenance window of one of your fellow tenants hosted on the same instance. If you open a case it can be investigated, and possibly you could be moved to a different host.

Comment: I thought instances on Azure were "silo-ed" from each other so as to not cause these types of effects?

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be seeing any type of daily window outtage. If you are, I would recommend you open up a support ticket and drive the issue through to resolution. Please also post the findings so we can all learn from it. :)